# How to combine multiple dictionaries in a list based on the given key columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a List which contains many dictionaries. Here I am trying to combine those dictionary into a single dict based on their key value. For illustration see the below example.

```
my_dict =[{'COLUMN_NAME': 'TABLE_1_COL_1', 'TABLE_NAME': 'TABLE_1'}, 
{'COLUMN_NAME': 'TABLE_1_COL_2', 'TABLE_NAME': 'TABLE_1'}, 
{'COLUMN_NAME': 'TABLE_1_COL_3', 'TABLE_NAME': 'TABLE_1'}, 
{'COLUMN_NAME': 'TABLE_2_COL_1', 'TABLE_NAME': 'TABLE_2'}, 
{'COLUMN_NAME': 'TABLE_2_COL_2', 'TABLE_NAME': 'TABLE_2'}]
```

Here for any key value matches with another key value then need to combine other key values.
Below is the sample output what I expect from the above list of dict.

```
new_lst = [{'TABLE_NAME': 'TABLE_1','COLUMN_NAME':['TABLE_1_COL_1','TABLE_1_COL_2','TABLE_1_COL_3']}, {'TABLE_NAME': 'TABLE_2','COLUMN_NAME': ['TABLE_2_COL_1','TABLE_2_COL_2']]
```

How can i achieve this in most efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that?

```
data = {}
for element in my_dict:
  table_name = element['TABLE_NAME']
  column_name = element['COLUMN_NAME']
  if table_name not in data:
    data[table_name] = []

  data[table_name].append(column_name)

new_lst = [{'TABLE_NAME': key, 'COLUMN_NAME': val} for key, val in data.items()]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `defaultdict` to get *similar* output.

```
from collections import defaultdict

new_lst = []

for some_dict in list_of_dicts:
    new_lst.append(defaultdict(list))

    for key, value in some_dict.items():
        new_lst[len(new_lst) - 1][key].append(value)
```

`new_lst` will be of the form:

```
[{'TABLE_NAME': ['TABLE_1'],'COLUMN_NAME':['TABLE_1_COL_1','TABLE_1_COL_2','TABLE_1_COL_3']}, {'TABLE_NAME': ['TABLE_2'],'COLUMN_NAME': ['TABLE_2_COL_1','TABLE_2_COL_2']]
```

Which is slightly different from what you wanted (even the singular elements are in arrays). I would recommend you *leave it* in this format if given the choice.

To get exactly what you wanted, add this after the above code:

```
for some_dict in new_lst:
    for key, value in some_dict.items():
        if len(value) == 1:
            some_dict[key] = value[0]
```

Now, `new_lst` is exactly like you expected:

```
[{'TABLE_NAME': 'TABLE_1','COLUMN_NAME':['TABLE_1_COL_1','TABLE_1_COL_2','TABLE_1_COL_3']}, {'TABLE_NAME': 'TABLE_2','COLUMN_NAME': ['TABLE_2_COL_1','TABLE_2_COL_2']]
```